# How to apply jQuery File Uploader (blueimp) on dynamically created inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

How to apply jQuery File Uploader (blueimp) on dynamically created input[type="files"].

All input files(file uploaders) have the same class, say "a".

All input(buttons) have the same class, say "uploaddata".

I tried the below jQuery but its not working it just pick the first fileuploader only.

```
 $('.a').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).fileupload({
            url: 'FileUploadHandler.ashx?upload=start',
        -------
         });
   });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if its dynamically created, try this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.a', function(){
        $(this).fileupload({
            url: 'FileUploadHandler.ashx?upload=start',
        -------
         });
   });
```

Comment: thanks @Gaurav its working, can we make it to work with button as well?, it should upload image on upload button.

Comment: one more question if all file up-loaders are not created dynamically and have the same class as it has.

Comment: @SunilChaudhry please share some code so i can understand your problem correctly.

Comment: I want the same thing but now from input[type="button"]. As shown in above image "upload button". Buttons are also dynamically created. Button should save file from the same row (from same row file uploader), pls let me know if still not clear.

Comment: buttons have the class "uploaddata" , jquery something like:-  jQuery(document).on('click', '.uploaddata', function (evt) {